# PHP - How to re-order data within a multidimensional array with only one reliable preceding string?

Tags: php

I am being passed inconsistent data. The problem is the individual rows of `$data_array` are not consistently in the same sequence but each has a reliable "text:" preceding the value.

Each row contains about 120 elements of data.  I only need 24 of those elements.

It's also possible one of the elements I need could be missing, such as "cost".

(I'm using php version 5.4)
-- Task:

Using $order_array, create a new $data_array_new by reordering the data in each "row" into the same sequence as $order_array.

If an elements is missing from a row insert "NA".

Once the elements are in the correct sequence the "text" is no longer required.

```
$order_array = array("price", "cost", "vol", "eps")
$data_array = Array (
    $one = Array ("cost":43.40, "vol":44000,   "eps":1.27,   "price":65.00),
    $two = Array ("eps":5.14,   "price":33.14, "vol":657000),
    $thr = Array ("vol":650000, "cost":66.67,  "eps":1.33,   "price":44.31),
);
```

The resulting ouput should appear with the data in this order: ("price", "cost", "vol", "eps")

```
$data_array_new = Array (
    $one = Array (65.00,43.40,44000,1.27),
    $two = Array (33.14,"NA",657000,5.14),
    $thr = Array (44.31,66.67,650000,1.33),
);
```

Comment: Why do I get a strong feeling this is a codewars question..?

Comment: First use `aray_filter` to make formatted subarray, and next `uasort` to create function to sort parent array.

Comment: Why don't you, at least, try something yourself? This would get rid of some syntax errors, and give us a starting point to help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The example code is generic. This is common for questions coming from sites like codewars. This is so you can provide an answer in your favorite language. Not just PHP. That's probably why there are syntax errors.

Comment: It's not a test.  I'm looking for ideas on how to approach this.  thanks bat03:  aray_filter and uasort are helpful ideas.  I'll probably need to become familiar with ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY as well.

Comment: this is what the raw incoming data looks like.  it isn't formatted the way I'd like it but it's what I have been handed.    These are four more of the 128 elements that are being passed. 
 Two of them have a label but no data. 
  "calculationPrice":"close","open":57.62,"openTime":1510756200098,

Comment: You are litterly copy/pasting a task that you're supposed to solve. Whether this is from some test or homework from school or even some selfstudy doesn't matter. The task was given to you by someone or something that thought you were ready for it. Now that on its own doesn't matter. But be truthfull about the context around your question. Because right now, you're not showing us any efford on your part to solve this problem. You're just asking us to solve it for you. - This is not me being an ass to you! It's just not the way Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the original incoming data here:  https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,tsla,ge&types=quote,earnings,stats

Here is the answer from : Andreas

Use json_decode on the string with the second parameter true and you get a associative array as output.

```
$url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?
symbols=aapl,tsla,ge&types=quote,earnings,stats";
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
Var_dump($arr);
```

See here;
I copied the string from the page and posted it as $str.
    https://3v4l.org/duWrI

Two steps is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_array_new = [];
foreach ($data_array as $index => $data) {
    $data_array_new[$index] = [];
    foreach ($order_array as $key) {
        if (isset($data[$key])) {
            $data_array_new[$index][] = $data[$key];
        } else {
            $data_array_new[$index][] = 'NA';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for the model code.  I can probably get this to work eventually.  I will first need to covert the ":" colons to "=>".  I think there's a typo in this line:   if (isset($data[$key]]) {.    I suspect it should end: $key][]){     I've never worked with nested arrays before.  I appreciate your efforts.